# Does window.stop() do anything if the window is already loaded?

Tags: javascript

In other words:

Is there a difference between

```
if (document.readyState !== "complete") window.stop();
```

and

```
window.stop();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

[`window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop) is like equivalent to clicking the stop button on the browser.

`if (document.readyState !== "complete") window.stop();` in this case, you just don't want to do it it if has already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You write "in this case, you just don't want to do it it if has already loaded." - so does it actually do anything if it has already loaded? Because if not, I can just leave out the `if`.

Comment: No it doesn't do anything it the page is alread loaded.. in JS `if() line of code before a Carriage Return/ Line break` is shorthand for `if() { line of code}`

Comment: sure, but does the `window.stop()` (without the `if`) do anything if the page is already loaded?

Comment: prevent ajax requests for instance

Comment: Yes as long as the request hasn't returned